# Where should the ray origin be put in perspective camera ray tracing?

Tags: raytracing

Where should the ray origin be put in perspective camera ray tracing?

The following gives a picture of the ray tracing in the perspective camera setting:
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2011fa/lectures/06raytracingWeb.pdf

and says that the $e$ is the ray origin, which is the same for all rays.

However, I don't understand how $e$ is supposed to be selected.
Can it be the zero vector? Or perhaps it is supposed to be the camera center?

Comment: You add a link but you don't say how it relates to your question. Please [edit] your question to explain fully what you understand and what you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you don't understand. All rays originate from the camera so It's basically the start of the camera's pyramid or more technically the viewing frustum.

[image]

Depends on the system you are using. Maybe your camera is fixed at the origin and only the world rotates/moves. In this case, usually the camera is fixed at the origin looking in either the +Z or -Z direction depending on if it's left or right handed coordinates system. So the ray origins will be fixed at `(0,0,0)`.

If your camera moves, however, the ray origins  also move to where you place the camera.

Comment: I'm given camera center point, so should I use it as $e$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the camera center? Cameras aren't usually defined using a center point. Maybe it's the eye position, check the diagram (it's the left most point from where all lines are emerging)

Comment: It's the center where the camera originates. The it also gives me $up$ vector, which points upwards from the camera, also an angle and a direction (where the camera points).

Comment: Yes then that's the camera's eye position, I haven't ever heard of it called by the name camera's center. Rays will originate from that point. Camera's are usually defined by 3 basis vectors, Side, Up and Look_at (X, Y, Z) respectively. The 4th vector is the Eye. Together these 4 vectors can make up the camera's view matrix.